# Python List of Dictionaries Denormalization

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

I have a list of list of dictionaries such as the following:

```
 [[{'ID': '1',
    'Value': '100'},
   {'ID': '2',
    'Value': '200'}],
 [{'ID': '2',
  'Value': '300'},
  {'ID': '2',
  'Value': '300'}],
  ...]]
```

I want to convert it into a denormalized dataframe which would have new column for each key such as:

```
#     ID Value ID  Value
#0    1  100   2    100
#1    2  300   2    300
```

If one item has 3 pairs of id, value those should be null for the other items. Running pd.DataFrame(list) creates only one ID and one Value column and puts the values under. How can we achieve this as seperate columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the `concat` function:

```
data = [pd.DataFrame(i) for i in input_data]
out = pd.concat(data, axis=1)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
  ID Value ID Value
0  1   100  2   300
1  2   200  2   300
```

The key is the `axis=1` which concatenates along the column axis.

## Edit:

Just saw the information with the zeros for all "shorter" columns. THis code results in `NaN` instead of zero, this however can be resolved fast with the `fillna()` method:

```
out = out.fillna(value=0)
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

input_data = [[{'ID': '1',
    'Value': '100'},
   {'ID': '2',
    'Value': '200'}],
 [{'ID': '2',
  'Value': '300'},
  {'ID': '2',
  'Value': '300'}],
 [{'ID': '2',
  'Value': '300'},
  {'ID': '2',
  'Value': '300'},
  {'ID': '3',
  'Value': '300'}]]

data = [pd.DataFrame(i) for i in input_data]
out = pd.concat(data, axis=1)
out = out.fillna(value=0)
print(out)
```

prints:

```
  ID Value ID Value ID Value
0  1   100  2   300  2   300
1  2   200  2   300  2   300
2  0     0  0     0  3   300
```